# Download google drive file with v3 api

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

The **Google drive api** seems confusing when it comes to [downloading](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads) files. I've been able to list all of the files and even downloaded few files but got stuck while downloading **Google docs**.

Why don't really they have common method for downloading a file but rather two different methods: **Get** and **Export**. When I don't need any conversion for the file, Why do I need to specify the **Mime type** for **Export**? Also, while listing files, the **Mime type** for all the files is always null. e.g

```
@foreach ($files->getFiles() as $file)
    {{  $file->getMimeType() }} // empty string / null
@endforeach
```

[Reference to getMimeType](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile.html#_getMimeType)

Here's what I've done so far

```
public function listFiles(Request $request)
  client = $this->getClient();
  $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
  $optParams = array(
    'q' => 'fullText contains \'"abc"\'',
    'pageSize' => 10,
    'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)'
  );
  $files = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);
}
public function downloadFile($file_id)
{
    $client = $this->getClient();
    $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
    $file = null;
    $file = $service->files->export($file_id, 'application/pdf', array(
            'alt' => 'media'
    )); // I really need to get rid of Mimetype(application/pdf), It should download the exact same file
}
```

**Update**

I have managed to solve the `mime type` problem by providing the field in the list.

```
$optParams = array(
        'q' => 'fullText contains \'"basheer"\'',
        'pageSize' => 10,
        'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType)' //<--
    );
```

But now when I try to download load the file, it throws the following error

> The requested conversion is not supported.  "domain": "global", "reason": "badRequest",

```
// request('mimeType') = application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet
$file = $service->files->export($file_id, request('mimeType'), array(
            'alt' => 'media'
        ));
```

Your answers and comments will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried reading through this?  https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads

Comment: @DaImTo I've gone through that many times.

Comment: ok what is the issue with your current solution then?

Comment: @DaImTo Can you please look into the updated section?

Comment: Mimetype isn't a mimetype application/pdf is you need to tell it what type of file you want it expired as.

Comment: @DaImTo The mimeType is now `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet` for a specific file which when used to export a file that throws error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167865/discussion-between-basheer-ahmed-kharoti-and-daimto).

Comment: @BasheerAhmedKharoti  How did you managed to solve this?

Comment: @Dimitrii I have defined a function to exchange the extension for google drive and the ask for the download.  https://kopy.io/niCzm

Comment: @BasheerAhmedKharoti What do you mean by the ask for the download, you ask the user to select in what format to download(export) the file?

Comment: @Dimitrii Here's how I download a single file https://kopy.io/3EZ7v